# What is this relay symbol?

Tags: relay, pid-controller

I have never seen a relay depicted as below:

[image: From SYL-2342 Datasheet] from [here (pdf)](http://auberins.com/images/Manual/Manual%20version%203.4.pdf)

Can someone explain what is going on for terminals 6, 7, and 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal 7 is the common point between a normally closed contact (terminal 6) and a normally open contact (terminal 8).

When the device is not powered, terminals 6 and 7 are connected. When the device activates terminals 6 and 7 open and terminals 7 and 8 close.

Answer (score 1):

Pins 6, 7 and 8 are a set of SPDT contacts. Pin 7 is the common, Pin 6 is the normally-closed contact, and pin 8 is the normally-open contact.